# Prove that $\mathrm E\left({\max}\left\{X^2 , Y^2\right\} \right) \leq 1 + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}$ where $\rho$ is their correlation.

Tags: probability

I have 2 random variables $X,Y$ with mean 0 and variance 1, their correlation is $\rho$. I need to prove this inequality

$$\mathrm E\left({\max}\left\{X^2 , Y^2\right\} \right) \leq 1 + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}$$
I need some pointers as to how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: If you know that their correlation $p$ is equal to $1$, what is $p$ doing in the equation below? Swap it for a $1$, and you'll have a much simpler right-hand side.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I changed it now

Comment: The $1$ on the right makes me want to write $\max(X^2,Y^2) = X^2 \phi + Y^2(1-\phi) = Y^2 + (X^2-Y^2)\phi$ with $\phi = \Bbb{1}_{X^2 > Y^2}$. Not sure if it helps.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395820/prove-that-exyx-y-leq-2-sqrt1-rho%C2%B2-where-rho-is-correlation?rq=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea: (I dont know if it will work out but it may be worth exploring)

You could use the fact that $max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$.
Then use the linearity of E, that gives you $E(max(X²,Y²)) \leq 1+\frac{E(|(X+Y)(X-Y)|)}{2}$
Now we just need to prove that $E(|(X+Y)(X-Y)|) \leq 2\sqrt{1-p²}$

Comment: That actually worked! Thanks , can't believe I didn't think of that

Comment: Also, there is an error in your equation, it's E(max(X²,Y²))≤1+E(|(X+Y)(X−Y)|)/2 and we need to prove E(|(X+Y)(X−Y)|)≤ 2*sqrt(1-p^2)

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you, I'll edit that right now