# Prove that $E(|(X+Y)(X-Y)|) \leq 2\sqrt{1-\rho²}$, where $\rho$ is correlation.

Tags: probability, expectation, regression

For two random variables $X,Y$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$, their correlation is $\rho$. We have to prove that

$$E(|(X+Y)(X-Y)|) \leq 2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}.$$

But, I can't understand how the $\rho$ will come under root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb E[XY] - \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y] $$
and
$$\rho = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(y)}}.$$
Now as $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[Y] = 0$, we have $$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb E[XY],$$ and as $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\operatorname{Var}(Y)=1$, it follows that $$\rho=\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb E[XY].$$
By Hölder's inequality, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[|(X+Y)(X-Y)|] &\leqslant \left(\mathbb E[|X+Y|^2]\mathbb E[|X-Y|^2]\right)^{\frac12}\\
&=\left((\mathbb E[X^2]+2\mathbb E[XY] + \mathbb E[Y^2])(\mathbb E[X^2]-2\mathbb E[XY]+\mathbb E[Y^2])\right)^{\frac12}\\
&=\left((2+2\mathbb E[XY])(2-2\mathbb E[XY] )\right)^{\frac12}\\
&= \left(4(1+\rho)(1-\rho)\right)^{\frac12}\\
&= 2(1-\rho^2)^{\frac12}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. You're a life saver.

Comment: You're welcome. This is more fun than work is :P

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**  By Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $E\Big(\big|(X+Y)(X-Y)\big|\Big)\leq \sqrt{E\Big(|X+Y|^2\Big)\cdot E\Big(|X-Y|^2\Big)}$.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, man.

Comment: Where did you get that idea from?  Expectation is a linear operator, and the equation you wrote is always correct even if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.